# Nelmio API doc area and bearer token with symfony 4

Tags: symfony, swagger, symfony4, nelmioapidocbundle

I have API in Symfony 4. I added NelmioApiDocBundle to my project, but i have problem with my docs. This is my configuration:
**packages\nelmio_api_doc.yaml**

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        #        schemes: [http, https]
        info:
            title: Symfony JWT API
            description: Symfony JWT API docs
            version: 1.0.0
        securityDefinitions:
            Bearer:
                type: apiKey
                description: 'Authorization: Bearer {jwt}'
                name: Authorization
                in: header
        security:
            - Bearer: []
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        default:
            path_patterns:
                - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
```

config\routes.yaml

```
# Expose your documentation as JSON swagger compliant
app.swagger_ui:
    path: /api/doc
    methods: GET
    defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui }
```

This i my swagger ui screen:
[image]

I have controller: SpeakerController, HomeController, How can I make each controller a separate area and the rest in default? i.e. SpeakerController in area Speaker, HomeController in area Home etc ..

My next problem is that I have an API protected by a bearer token, when I click Authorize in the swagger, I will add the current jwt token and I want to request it, in response I get:

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "JWT Token not found"
}
```

In postman i don't have problem:
[image]

Comment: Wrt the bearer token issue - when you enter the token in Swagger UI, do you prefix it with `Bearer `?

Comment: @Helen yes, i add prefix Bearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must send  apiKey value with a prefix

> Bearer

[image]

Comment: Hi :) Your answer solved my problem. I forgot add Bearer on begin, and i typed  only token.

Comment: Also you can change or remove this prefix in config

Comment: Since you are using Bearer Authentication (With the word "Bearer") you can use this config:
components:
            securitySchemes:
                Bearer:
                    type: http
                    scheme: bearer
                    bearerFormat: JWT
        security:
            - Bearer: []

Answer (score 0):

You will need to annotate your controllers with tags:

```
@SWG\Tag(name="Speaker")
```

See:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html#using-the-bundle

Comment: Works good, but i have problem with bearer token, i added good token, but when i do request i have error "JWT Token not found"

Comment: @PawelC did you annotate your controller with ```@Security(name="Bearer")```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The token was not sent in the request when clicking on **"Try it out"**.

My config was OK, but I wasn't telling Nelmio to use it in my controllers.

As commented by @Marcello Kad, you can use this config:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
documentation:
    info:
        title: BaBaLex
        description: Base Lexicale Lex:gaMe
        version: 1.0.0
    components:
        securitySchemes:
            MySecurityScheme:
                type: http
                scheme: bearer
                bearerFormat: JWT
    security:
        - MySecurityScheme: []
```

And in the controller, in the action'sannotation, **don't forget this:**

```
@Security(name="MySecurityScheme")
```